# Three.js get json

Tags: javascript, three.js

I know how to export a json model from blender and load it with THREE.JSONLoader().load. I want to build a model with Threejs in Webgl and create a json file from that model. Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I guess, you need to take a look at ThreeJS Editor: http://threejs.org/editor/

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to understand your question before. Are you trying to bundle your object3D in a JSON, just like it was an .obj? So you can read it and build the geometry in another moment in another place?
It seems you are trying to make the inverse path "blender -> json -> three.js", that's right?

In my opinion you should understand exactly how a model is coded into a JSON, so that you can act like you were blender, and just then you should write something like a serializer that bundles the right information in a JSON.

If you just want to create a JSON that could act as a custom pattern/model/standard, something like an alternative to .obj or .blend format, then you should also write down a de-serializer.

Let me explain.

Your geometry has vertices, faces, uvs, normals, and so on. You have to specify all those things while serializing, following a precise order, and then you are done. Once that you know the paradigm you are able to read it and de-serialize it.

If I misunderstood something, please tell me.

Bye bye

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.
You'll need a plugin installed in blender to export to Three.js.

**Download form git**: [Blender exporter to Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender)

So, download it and put the io_three folder under your ~/.config/blender/2.69/scripts/addons/ folder.

Then, open the File > User preferences and go to the Addons tab. Search for Three.js and enable the found plug-in. Now, you should be able to see a File > Export > Three.js option. On the opened tab, ensure that Face Materials checkbox is checked. Otherwise, you won’t have materials, and Three.js is going to refuse to import your mesh.

**Using with Three.js**

```
var mesh = null;
function initMesh() {
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('./marmelab-logo.json', function(geometry) {
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
        scene.add(mesh);
    });
}
```